# Function to replace not in html code

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to understand how to do a replace of a string that also contains html code (in ColdFusion).

**The function must not look (or replace) for inside html tags.**

Thank you.

Let me be more specific:
should not search inside the *img* and *a* tag

Comment: in order for others to help you, please expand your question giving examples of what you are attempting to achieve and what you have tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ColdFusion only deals with strings, it doesn't know anything about "HTML", it just sees "string data". So thee's nothing native in ColdFusion to help you.

I haven't tried this, but you could perhaps use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) to convert the string into a usable DOM document, then you will be able to distinguish between tags and text.